# Why Picture Rotate after taking Pic from android:hardware:camera api

Tags: android, image, api, camera, rotation

I am using android:hardware:camera API to make custom camera . i have done to make the camera but problem is that after taking picture from camera the pic save in rotated form.I am using Surface View for the Camera .
this is Camera setting function on surface-created

Comment: The reason pictures are rotated is the because of the cameras orientation. You can read images exif data to figure out its orientation.

Answer (score 4):

```
try {
    File f = new File(imagePath);
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    int angle = 0;

    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        angle = 90;
    } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        angle = 180;
    } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        angle = 270;
    }

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(angle);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),
            null, options);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstudentstreamOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
            outstudentstreamOutputStream);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
} catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
    Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
}
```

try this after capture image from camera to rotate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below method to show/save image in actual orientation.

```
public static Bitmap setImage(String filePath, Bitmap bitmap){
    File curFile = new File(filePath);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(curFile.getPath());
        int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (rotation != 0.0f) {matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);}
        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotatedBitmap;
}

private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; }
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }
    return 0;
}
```